# Python class with functions that call and minimize other functions

Tags: python, class, optimization, scipy, compiler-optimization

I am trying to write a function within a class that is trying to minimise another function.

What is the correct way to write and call it ? I am stuck and I am not sure how to do this.

```
import pandas as pd
import scipy.optimize as sco

class Optimisation:
    def __init__(self, rf, expected_return, cov):
 
        self.rf = rf
        self.expected_return = expected_return
        self.cov = cov

    def calculate_negative_sharpe(self):
        self.portfolio_return = np.sum(expected_returns * weights) * 252
        self.portfolio_std = np.sqrt(np.dot(self.weights.T, np.dot(self.cov, self.weights))) * np.sqrt(252)
        self.sharpe_ratio = (self.portfolio_return - self.rf) / self.portfolio_std
        return -self.sharpe_ratio



    def max_sharpe_ratio(expected_returns, cov, rf):
        num_assets = len(expected_returns)
        args = (expected_returns, cov, rf)
        constraints = ({'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x: np.sum(x) - 1})
        bound = (0.0,1.0)
        bounds = tuple(bound for asset in range(num_assets))
        result = sco.minimize(calculate_negative_sharpe, num_assets*[1./num_assets,], args=args, method='SLSQP', bounds=bounds, constraints=constraints)
        return result

opt = Optimisation(rf, er, cov)
result = opt.max_sharpe_ratio()
print(result)
```

or should it be like

```
import pandas as pd
import scipy.optimize as sco

class Optimisation:
    def __init__(self, rf, expected_return, cov):
 
        self.rf = rf
        self.expected_return = expected_return
        self.cov = cov

    def calculate_negative_sharpe(self):
        self.portfolio_return = np.sum(expected_returns * weights) * 252
        self.portfolio_std = np.sqrt(np.dot(self.weights.T, np.dot(self.cov, self.weights))) * np.sqrt(252)
        self.sharpe_ratio = (self.portfolio_return - self.rf) / self.portfolio_std
        return -self.sharpe_ratio



    def max_sharpe_ratio(self):
        self.num_assets = len(self/expected_returns)
        self.args = (self.expected_returns, self.cov, self.rf)
        self.constraints = ({'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x: np.sum(x) - 1})
        self.bound = (0.0,1.0)
        self.bounds = tuple(self.bound for asset in range(self.num_assets))
        self.result = sco.minimize(self.calculate_negative_sharpe, self.num_assets*[1./self.num_assets,], args=self.args, method='SLSQP', bounds=self.bounds, constraints=self.constraints)
        return self.result

opt = Optimisation(rf, er, cov)
result = opt.max_sharpe_ratio()
print(result)
```

My goal is to return a result dataframe which I can print or save.

Comment: Methods in a class should have a `self` argument.

Comment: Should there be a self attached to every variable ?

Comment: Every method, yes.  `def mymethod(self, other, arguments):`.

Comment: I mean within the method, does everything need to be self as well?

Comment: The `__init__` defines 3 variables, `self.rf` etc.  Each time you use them, you use the full name.  The `self` identifies a variable that "belongs" to the class instance.  That also applies to methods.  But if a variable is just used within a method, it doesn't need the `self`.  It's local to the method   Scope rules for methods are basically the same as for functions.